# Is there a word for this condition?

Tags: word-request

A ball filled completely with air is said to be inflated.
What do you say if a ball is in a 'not that much inflated' condition? Is there a single word for it?
Are there other words that give the same meaning as that of inflated/'not so inflated'

Comment: The prefix [**semi-**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/semi-?s=t) can be applied to lots of different adjectives, including this one.  "Semi-inflated" means "partially inflated."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Underinflated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underinflated) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If it had once been gas filled, it could be deflated

> deflated ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 Having been emptied of air or gas.
>
> ‘a deflated balloon’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deflated